# Custom Edge visualization in Networkx

Tags: networkx, graph-theory

I'm trying to display an electrical circuit. 
Is there any way to replace the line(that appears as an edge) with a resistor.

Comment: It is neither a reasonable option nor a simple one although you can create a several nodes and zigzag edges to represent a resistor.

Comment: you are likely to have more success with a specialised circuit-drawing package, e.g. https://cdelker.bitbucket.io/SchemDraw/SchemDraw.html